# Opencart - How to display only category and its children of a product?

Tags: opencart, categories

I'm a newbie to opencart and I gave up at solving this problem. I want to display only categories that the product belongs to (includes its sub and sub children) in module category at the left sidebar of product page. Thank so much and sorry for bad english.

Comment: have you tried any code ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getProductCategories($product_id) {
    $product_category_data = array();

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");

    foreach ($query->rows as $result) {
        $product_category_data[] = $result['category_id'];
    }

    return $product_category_data;
}
```

add this function to your catalog/product model, call it at your product controller as

```
$product_categories = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductCategories($your_product_id);
```

you will get an array of category id's. Then you can get category information as:

```
$this->data['categories'] = array();
$this->load->model('catalog/category');

foreach($product_categories as $category_id){
  $this->data['categories'][] = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($category_id);
}
```